# implementing ASCII values using Left and Right shift in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to do left and right shifting of the ASCII values but my method (show below) is giving the correct values for 0, but where it has to show 1 it gives me output like this:

```
the values of asciiValue in getLeastbit function 98 shift 0
temp value0
the values of asciiValue in getLeastbit function 97 shift -2147483648
temp value1
```

What is the problem as I am not able to resolve it.

```
int getleastbit(int asciiValue) {
    int temp;
    temp = asciiValue << 31;
    //System.out.println("temp value for checking"+temp);
    System.out.println("the values of asciiValue in getLeastbit function "+asciiValue+" shift "+temp);
    temp = temp >>> 31;
    System.out.println("temp value"+temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: The massive negative value you get with input `97` looks like something is going on with the sign bit.

Comment: What output **did** you expect?

Comment: Its most likely because of overflow. I haven't code tested this, but 1100010(binary of 98) and then 31 zeros will make it overflow 32 bit Integer value. Change all types to long and check.

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct. `-2147483648` is `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` in 32-bit binary (Java's `int`'s format). You end up with the LSB (least significant bit) in the position of the MSB (most significant bit).

Answer (score 0):

While shifting 31 bits (`<<` and `>>`) we are left with:

`asciiValue << 31
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

But when we shift using unsigned right shift:

`asciivalue >>> 31

-2147483648 is 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

**On a side note** when you shift an integer with the `<<` or `>>` operator and the shift distance is greater than or equal to 32, you take the shift distance `mod` 32. It means you mask off all but the low order 5 bits of the shift distance.

For example `(i >> 32) == i`, for every integer `i`. You might expect it to shift the entire number off to the right, returning 0 for positive inputs and -1 for negative inputs, but it doesn't; it simply returns `i`, because `(i << (32 & 0x1f)) == (i << 0) == i`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i= 40;
        System.out.println(i>>31);
        System.out.println(i>>32);
        System.out.println(i<<31);
        System.out.println(i<<32);
    }
```

Output:

`0
40
0
40`

Comment: Huh? That doesn't answer the question. The OP never shifts by more than 31 bits.

Comment: When he shifts by 31 bits he gets a `0` and that explains it. It also goes further to explain that if you shift one more time you get the int itself.

Answer (score 0):

You do a 31 byte left shift. As you know, a left shift operation basically doubles the number you entered for each shifting operation. Eg. 1 << 1 = 2, 2 << 1 = 4, etc. You can do a small program for testing why it gives for 97 a negative value:

`int a = 97;
      for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
          a = a << 1;
          System.out.println(a);
      }`

You will see (some of ) the following values: 194, 388, 776, ..., 1627389952, -1040187392, -2080374784, 134217728, ..., -2147483648. Since your number is 97 we know that 31 shifting operations will generate a number greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE, so overflow will occur. In this case, the shifting operation will behave like expected, the most significant byte is discarded and a new 0 is added as the least significant byte. Since you do 31 shifts and your number was odd, you will have 1 followed by 31 zeros, which is a negative integer value. So if you wish to see if you have 0 or 1 as the last byte, if you have this negative value, always you have a 1, else is 0 for the last byte on the original number.